# Laravel combining two tables and calculating values from one of them

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables in the database: counters and counter history. I would like to receive a table with counters and for each counter, from the table 'countershistory' subtracting the first and last value from the 'value' column and pass it to the counters as counterhistory_value. Here is the code I currently have

```
$counters= Counter::all()
->select('countershistory.value as counterhistory_value')
->join('countershistory', 'countershistory.counter_id', '=', 'counter.id')
->groupBy('id')
->get();
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: When you say "the first and last value" are you trying to subtract the first history value from the last based on when they were created in the database?  What about all the other values that are inserted between the first and last?

Comment: Either be more specific, or provide an example of what you're after.

Comment: From where do you expect to get the first and last value ?